# With mv, possible to put a time dependence on files mv'ed?

Tags: command-line, files, timestamps, mv

Let's say there's a specific time and date I have in mind.  All files last edited before this date I want to keep in the directory but all files that have been edited since this date I want to `mv` somewhere else.  The `man` page of `mv` doesn't show this being possible with `mv` directly.  I thought some form of the the following should work:

```
ls -t | head -n $number
```

Where `$number` specifies the number of files that have been edited since the time and date I had in mind.  I could then somehow feed this to `mv` to `mv` those files (haven't thought up exactly how to do that).  The disadvantage of this is that I would have to count up how many files have been edited since the date and time I had in mind.  Is there a way where I can just specify a date and time and let my computer figure out which files need to be `mv`ed and `mv` them for me?  If not, then how would I complete the command I have written above to feed those file names to `mv` to have them all `mv`ed to the same location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /path/to/dir -mtime +5 -exec mv {} /target/path/ ';'
```

will move all files in `/path/to/dir` that are older than five days to /target/path.

You can try this to see what will actually be executed:

```
find /path/to/dir -mtime +5 -exec echo mv {} /target/path/ ';'
```

Note that the `-mtime` parameter checks the file's modification time. Have a look at `-ctime` or `-atime` in [find's manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for more detail.

If you want to specify your times in minutes, use one of `-mmin`, `-cmin` and `-amin` instead.

To find files younger than a specific amount of time, use `-` instead of `+`, e.g. `-mmin -30`.

Another method would be to use `xargs` (which will execute a command with each of its input lines; [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs)):

```
find /path/to/dir -mtime +5|xargs -i echo mv {} /target/path
```

(remove the 'echo' to actually move stuff)

Comment: What if I want something less than five days?  Like, say 30 minute?

Comment: use `find`'s `-mmin` parameter

Comment: My guess from my own experimentation is that changing the argument to `-mtime` from `+5` to `-5` will move all files that are *younger* than five days.  Correct?

Comment: And what does the `';'` do at the end of the command?  I understand what everything else in the command does.

Comment: When you use `find`'s `-exec` parameter, it will send each of the following arguments to the subprocess until it finds the single ';'.

Comment: "Older than five days" means "at least six days" in this case, right?  From what I understand from the `man` page, what you have written here will ignore files that were modified 5.9 days ago, because of rounding.

Comment: Yes, but that's 'more than 5*24h before now'; if you want actual days, use `-daystart` instead. But it's all described in the manpage and not that hard to test without breaking stuff (if you put an `echo` before the execution commands)